# Get default theme name

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, theme, design, package

I have my Magento package/theme structure configured like this:

In Configuration -> General -> Design:

In the **package** section the text "default".
In the **themes** section I have all the inputs empty except for the default input where I have introduced the name of my theme: "mytheme".

I need to get the package && theme name by code.

I have no problems with the package name:

```
Mage::getDesign('core/design_package')->getPackageName()
```

This code returns "default", which is perfect.

But when I try to get the theme name, I cannot get the text "mytheme".

```
Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('frontend');
Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('layout');
Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template');
Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('skin');
Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('locale');
```

The different approachs return always "default".

If I introduce and save the name of my theme for example in the "layout" input, I can get it with:

```
Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('layout');
```

**But how I can get the text of the "default" input?**

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('design/theme/template');
Mage::getStoreConfig('design/theme/layout');
Mage::getStoreConfig('design/theme/skin');
Mage::getStoreConfig('design/theme/locale');
Mage::getStoreConfig('design/theme/default');
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('default');
```

Comment: Yep, it doesn't seem to be a valid option. The types array only contains "skin", "locale", "template" and "layout" options.

Comment: I guess you can just do Mage::getStoreConfig('design/theme/default'); right ?

Comment: Doesn't work either. Maybe could be because I'm executing it from an admin controller? (I set the area before). It also has a parent theme defined in theme.xml

Comment: Try using your frontend store id as the second parameter of the getStoreConfig function.

Comment: still not working from a custom admin controller although I can see it in the database with scope_id 0. I'm using this code: Mage::getStoreConfig('design/theme/default', Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId())

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('design/theme/default');
```